# How to change the background color of the input in NextUI

Tags: reactjs, nextui

I'm trying to change the background color of the `Input` component from NextUI. I already tried to use `styled` attribute but no luck.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background color of the input using the `css` property and modifying the **$$inputColor** variable, as follows:

```js
import { Input } from "@nextui-org/react";

export default function App() {
  return <Input placeholder="Next UI" css={{ $$inputColor: "#330025" }} />;
}
```

Here's a Codesandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/nextui-input-custom-background-5d83on?file=/App.js:0-154

Answer (score 0):

You can change background with prop classnames and edit input json

```
import { Input } from "@nextui-org/react";

<Input
 type="email"
 label="Email"
 classNames={{ input: 'bg-red-400' }}
/>
```